# ASP error 'ASP 0115', but for only one user

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Classic ASP application on a locally hosted server (IIS7). Everyone else in the organization can access this application just fine. This specific user encounters the following error:

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0115' 
Unexpected error 
/OurApp/OurApp.asp
A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running.
```

I've found [this article on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194190/en-us). However, since all users bar one are able to access this application, the problem doesn't seem to be a general permissions problem.

What might be causing this specific user to run into errors?

Answer (score 0):

0xC0000005 is the access violation error, its not about permission, is about attempting to read or write protected memory. There must be a user based logic in the `OurApp.asp` script or one or more components in it which attempts to read or write protected memory just in case of this specific user.

Comment: Nothing in the script mentions this user specifically. Indeed, the only time a user is dealt with in this application is during the initial authentication.

Comment: @rwhite I don't mean directly this user is mentioned in the code. For example accessing user attribute  in the Active Directory or user properties in the Database or even checking the User-Agent header in the `Request.ServerVariables`.